# C# Windows Forms DatagridView Filtering

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datagridview, dataset

I have a dataGridView control on a form.

I have a dataSet of a SQL database created in the project.

I can easily bind a table to my dataGridView control, and the tableAdapter fills the dataGridView - no problem.

Now, I have been through every forum and FAQ but cannot, for the life of me, get the defaultView.rowFilter() function to work on the dataTable bound to the dataGridView.

I had it working perfectly once before with none of the complicated and confusing work-arounds that almost every other answer seems to give. In fact the filtering worked with this simple one-liner:

```
(dataGridCustomers.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("'{0}' LIKE '{1}%' OR '{0}' LIKE '%{1}%' ", columnName, txtFilterTxt.Text);
```

I have tried all sorts of things, such as messing around with creating dataTables and bindingSources separate from the main dataSet that I am using throughout my project, but to no avail.

And as I have said - I have been through what feels like dozens of forums but cannot find the simple method that I had working before which is why I'm resorting to asking my own question which I rarely do.

I feel like it should be simple - what am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have Column names in quotes? -- I don't see how using a BindingSource as DataSource of your DGV makes things *complicated*. In that case, it's just `(dataGridCustomers.DataSource as BindingSource).Filter = "...";`. But you have extra tools to work with (and the DataSource of the BindindSource can be something else entirely, but you use the same methods)

Comment: @Jimi Good question, I copied this from an older project and didn't realise them - guess they don't make a difference. Okay, in fairness, I'm certain it's not actually complicated... but I have not been able to find a single tutorial that actually goes through each step of the process. I also tried that line of code as you suggested, but same issue - it just leaves the dataGridView empty until I clear the filter query.

Comment: @Jimi Scrap that about the quotes; removing them does raise a "syntax error: missing operand before 'OR' operator". Well, it's about 2.30am and I don't care enough haha

Comment: You probably have removed the quotes also from the values. The filter should be `string.Format("{0} LIKE '{1}%' OR {0} LIKE '%{1}%' ", columnName, txtFilterTxt.Text);`. Or `$"{columnName} LIKE '{txtFilterTxt.Text}%' OR {columnName} LIKE '%{txtFilterTxt.Text}%'";`

Comment: @Jimi I want to bang my head against a wall… let’s just say that the syntax error is not the only thing it fixed. I shouldn’t be up at this time of night… thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi) for the suggestion of using a binding source (as well as removing the quotes around my filter query):

> Why do you have Column names in quotes? -- I don't see how using a BindingSource as DataSource of your DGV makes things complicated. In that case, it's just `(dataGridCustomers.DataSource as BindingSource).Filter = "...";`. But you have extra tools to work with (and the DataSource of the BindindSource can be something else entirely, but you use the same methods)

> You probably have removed the quotes also from the values. The filter should be `string.Format("{0} LIKE '{1}%' OR {0} LIKE '%{1}%' ", columnName, txtFilterTxt.Text);`. Or `$"{columnName} LIKE '{txtFilterTxt.Text}%' OR {columnName} LIKE '%{txtFilterTxt.Text}%'";`

Everything seems to be working fine now.